# CodeIgniter - How do I get session to detect whether user is logged in?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have very simple page that requires login to view. I have a login controller and view that will redirect to the main page after successful login. However, i want to detect whether user is logged in if the user directly access the main page link, if not logged in, then the user should be redirect back to the login page.

My Login controller:

```
<?php  
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

class Login extends CI_Controller {  

    public function index()  
    {  
        $this->load->view('login_view');  
    }  
    public function process()  
    {  
        $user = $this->input->post('user');  
        $pass = $this->input->post('pass');  
        if ($user=='admin' && $pass=='123')   
        {  
            $this->session->set_userdata(array('user'=>$user));  
            redirect("Report");
        }  
        else{  
            $data['error'] = 'Your Account is Invalid';  
            $this->load->view('login_view', $data);  
        }  
    }  
    public function logout()  
    {  
        $this->session->unset_userdata('user');  
        redirect("Login");  
    }  
}  
?>
```

and my Login view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Login Page</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <?php echo isset($error) ? $error : ''; ?>  
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('Login/process'); ?>">  
        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">  
            <tr>  
                <td><th>Username:</th></td>  
                <td><input type="text" name="user"></td>  
            </tr>  
            <tr>  
                <td><th>Password:</th></td>  
                <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>  
            </tr>  
            <tr>  
                <td> </td>  
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>  
            </tr>  
        </table>  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

while the login process is working good, but i'm not sure how to get the session from my main page to detect whether user is logged in. I know i should add some validation in the main controller but i'm not sure how, please help thank you.

main controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class EstoreReport extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('ReportModel');
}

public function index()
{
   $report=new ReportModel;
   $data['data']=$report->get_report();
   $this->load->view('includes/header');
   $this->load->view('Report/list',$data);
   $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple configure in your controller `index()`: 
Use `$this->session->userdata('user') == NULL` to check whether user is logged in

```
 public function index()
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('user') == NULL)
   { 
      redirect('Login');
   }
   else
   {
      $report=new ReportModel;
      $data['data']=$orders->get_report();
      $this->load->view('includes/header');
      $this->load->view('Report/list',$data);
      $this->load->view('includes/footer');
   }
}
```

Comment: By using this method you will have repetitive if/else statements in every method. The smarter thing to do is call a 'is_loggedin' method that redirects to the login screen if user isn't logged in.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function and call it to check whether the user is logged in or not

```
 public function is_logged_in()
    {
        $user = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
        return isset($user);
    }
```

Comment: where do i call the function ? and what does `$user` return ?

Comment: You can call it where you want to check if the user is logged in or not. It will return true or false. If it return true then the user is logged in otherwise not

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have session helper autoloaded, just like validation on the `Login` controller, you could set the validation in the `index` method of the Main / Report controller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class EstoreReport extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('ReportModel');
}

public function index()
{
    if (!isset($this->session->userdata('user'))) {
        redirect("Login");  
    } else {
        $report=new ReportModel;
        $data['data']=$report->get_report();
        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('Report/list',$data);
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$this->session->has_userdata()` as per CI [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

So

```
// Write a boolean returning method
/**
* Returns if there is a user session
*
* @return bool
*/
public function isLoggedIn()
{
    return $this->session->has_userdata($some_defined_key_like_user_id);
}

...

// Then in your index controller method
/**
* Index controller method
*
* @return void
*/
public function index()
{
    $this->isLoggedIn() ? $this->load()->view('login') : redirect("Report");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have true or false from below function call, Call this function in your controller and then redirect as per the response.

```
$this->session->userdata( 'logged_in' );
```

Comment: should i call this function in index() ? sorry i',m a very new codeigniter user

Answer (score 0):

controller

```
public function index()
{
    //redirect to dashboard
    $this->dashboard();
}
public function dashboard()
{ //session wise operating isset session-> dashboard ,else login page
    if ($this->session->userdata('userName')) {
         //if user found
        return $this->load->view('dashboard');
    } else {
        //if "no user found"
        return $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
public function login_check()
{ //functions retrives two values 1-user type 2-userId
    $data['userdata'] = $this->Mdl_login->Login_check();

    if ($data['userdata'] == false) {
        $this->load->view('login', $data);
    } else {
        redirect(base_url('index.php/dashboard'), 'refresh');
    }
}
function logout()
{ //session destroy function
    $this->session->unset_userdata('userName');
   redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
}
```

Model

```
 function Login_check()
{
    $username = $this->input->post('UserName');
    $password = $this->input->post("PassWord");

    //check with your value 
    $this->db->where('userName', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $qry_getuserdata = $this->db->get('user_tbl');
    if ($qry_getuserdata->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result = $qry_getuserdata->result();
        $userid = $result[0]->userId;
        $usertype = $result[0]->userType;
        $email = $result[0]->email;
        $this->session->set_userdata('userName', $username);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userId', $userid);
        $this->session->set_userdata('userType', $usertype);
        $this->session->set_userdata('email', $email);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you can access your session data anywhere

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userName'])){ $data['userName']= $_SESSION['userName']; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    class Login extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('loginmodel', 'login');
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
        }

        public function index() {
            $this->load->view('admin/login');
        }

        // Check for user login process
        public function user_aouth() {

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');
                redirect('login');
            } else {
                $username = $this->input->post('username');
                $password = $this->input->post('password');
                $data = array(
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password
                );
                if ($this->login->check_valid_user_details($data)) {
                    $session_data = array(
                        'username' => $username
                    );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
//redirect to admin user dashboard
                    redirect('dashboard');
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');
                    redirect('login');
                }
            }
        }

        public function logout() {
            $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect('login');
        }

    }
```

In your login model

```
public function check_valid_user_details($data) {
        $condition = "username=" . "'" . $data['username'] . "'" . "AND password=" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'";
        $c = $this->db->select('*')
                ->from('admin')
                ->where($condition)
                ->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Use this at the top of every page under dashboard

```
 if($this->session->userdata('username') == NULL){ 
     redirect('login');
}
```